# php no transfer sessions blank or null result

Tags: php, session, curl

Hello I want to create a $_SESSION variable but it doesn't work when I remove curl_setopt
This is the code

This calls the function
`CurlProxy::iniprox($url);`

This is the function that at the same time calls iniprox

```
    static public function iniprox($url)
    {
        if (self::lerox($url))
            \add_action('http_api_curl', array(__CLASS__, 'addProxy'), 10, 3);
    }
```

When I run the session it passes successfully
(On call $_SESSION["proxyactual"] in other page it successfully returns the variable **$proxy**)

```
static public function addProxy($handle, $r, $url)
    {
        $_SESSION["proxyactual"] = "proxy";
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
        error_log( 'Detecta servidor proxy!' );
}
```

But when I do it like this the session does not pass
On another page calling $_SESSION["proxyactual"] returns empty.
It should return **"noproxy"**

```
static public function addProxy($handle, $r, $url)
    {
        $_SESSION["proxyactual"] = "noproxy";
        error_log( 'Detecta servidor proxy!' );
}
```

As you can see just remove **curl_setopt**

Edit: I discovered that the code keeps executing and does not wait for CurlProxy::iniprox($url); that's why it doesn't find value since the function CurlProxy::iniprox($url); assign the value.

How can I make CurlProxy::iniprox($url); finish executing and continue executing the code?

Comment: Please be more descriptive of what you mean by "it passes" and "it does not pass". What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: I edited the question thanks for your comment and appreciation

Comment: session is valid with the session cookie, use `session_start()`

Comment: That is present in both documents
The $_SESSION stops working only when I remove the line curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);

Comment: Are you certain that the script actually completes without error? Also, the logic of calling a function named `addProxy()` that does not add a proxy is suspect. I would suspect that the function is simply not being called, and also consider altering the workflow to be more sensible.

Comment: add a try and catch to check and the function completes without errors.
I don't understand why the session doesn't pass just by removing the curl_setopt line

Comment: I discovered that the code keeps executing and does not wait for CurlProxy::iniprox($url); that's why it doesn't find value since the function CurlProxy::iniprox($url); assign the value.

How can I make CurlProxy::iniprox($url); finish executing and continue executing the code?

Comment: Your `iniprox()` method only sends a callback function to `add_action()`. Whether or not that function is actually _executed_, and when that happens, depends on the code inside `add_action()` and probably other factors. See example: https://3v4l.org/rMl8j